# DNS lookups with/without recursion in NSLOOKUP

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nslookup

I am playing around with NSLOOKUP trying to learn about recursive DNS lookups. I am looking up a bogus host name and I seem to be getting the same results whether I enable or disable recursion.

With Recursion:

```
nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

> set recurse
> set debug
> nytimes
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
    header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.intranet.contoso.com, type = A, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  intranet.contoso.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
    primary name server = DNSSERVER.intranet.contoso.com
    responsible mail addr = hostmaster.intranet.contoso.com
    serial  = 10301
    refresh = 900 (15 mins)
    retry   = 600 (10 mins)
    expire  = 86400 (1 day)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
    header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.intranet.contoso.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  intranet.contoso.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
    primary name server = DNSSERVER.intranet.contoso.com
    responsible mail addr = hostmaster.intranet.contoso.com
    serial  = 10301
    refresh = 900 (15 mins)
    retry   = 600 (10 mins)
    expire  = 86400 (1 day)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
    header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.contoso.com, type = A, class = IN
ANSWERS:
->  nytimes.contoso.com
    internet address = 74.125.226.195
    ttl = 1800 (30 mins)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
    header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.contoso.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  contoso.com
    ttl = 900 (15 mins)
    primary name server = dns01.gpn.register.com
    responsible mail addr = partnersupport.register.com
    serial  = 2002050701
    refresh = 10800 (3 hours)
    retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
    expire  = 604800 (7 days)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
Name:    nytimes.contoso.com
Address:  74.125.226.195

>
```

With NO Recursion:

```
nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

> set norecurse
> set debug
> nytimes
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
    header flags:  response, auth. answer, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.intranet.contoso.com, type = A, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  intranet.contoso.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
    primary name server = DNSSERVER.intranet.contoso.com
    responsible mail addr = hostmaster.intranet.contoso.com
    serial  = 10301
    refresh = 900 (15 mins)
    retry   = 600 (10 mins)
    expire  = 86400 (1 day)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
    header flags:  response, auth. answer, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.intranet.contoso.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  intranet.contoso.com
    ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
    primary name server = DNSSERVER.intranet.contoso.com
    responsible mail addr = hostmaster.intranet.contoso.com
    serial  = 10301
    refresh = 900 (15 mins)
    retry   = 600 (10 mins)
    expire  = 86400 (1 day)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
    header flags:  response, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.contoso.com, type = A, class = IN
ANSWERS:
->  nytimes.contoso.com
    internet address = 74.125.226.195
    ttl = 1526 (25 mins 26 secs)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
------------
Got answer:
HEADER:
    opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
    header flags:  response, recursion avail.
    questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

QUESTIONS:
    nytimes.contoso.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
AUTHORITY RECORDS:
->  contoso.com
    ttl = 626 (10 mins 26 secs)
    primary name server = dns01.gpn.register.com
    responsible mail addr = partnersupport.register.com
    serial  = 2002050701
    refresh = 10800 (3 hours)
    retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
    expire  = 604800 (7 days)
    default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
Name:    nytimes.contoso.com
Address:  74.125.226.195

>
```

It looks like it is using recursion even when I set it to off. The funny thing is if I look up the bogus hostname specifying 4.2.2.2 as the DNS server then the recursion setting does take effect. Anyone know why this is happening?

BTW I sanitized the host names

Answer (score 3):

The server returns authoritative responses for the domain when you have `norecurse` set, in addition to being willing to perform recursion for you. It won't matter whether the recursion flag is set or not.

> Got answer:
>   HEADER:
>   header flags:  **response**, **auth. answer**, **recursion avail.**